# github forked repository: How to pull the changes from forkedrepo/branch to orignalrepo/<Create-new-branch>

Tags: github, git-branch, git-push, git-pull, git-fork

UserA Original Repository Creator:  No branches. Master only. 
UserB Forks the repository and makes some changes and creates a new branch and puts the changes into github.com/**userB**/repo-name/newbranch-name

How can userA ,

1. pull the changes from github.com/**userB**/repo-name/newbranch-name
   and
2. put into a new branch with the same name as of userB ....that
       is, github.com/**userA**/repo-name/newbranch-name

**Some info on current scenario** 
UserB(forked user) is not available to push those changes - the question is not "how can I get  to do something" but "how can I do something myself" without requesting userB to push the changes to UserA (Original repo creator)

 In addition, UserA  doesnt want to merge this to MASTER. 

 UserA prefers to put these changes in a new branch. ***i.e.*** **github.com/UserA/repo-name/{create-new-branch}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add userB's repository as a remote, pull it to a new branch locally, then push it to userA's repository:

```
git remote add userA github.com/userA/repo-name
git remote add userB github.com/userB/repo-name
git pull userB newbranch-name
git push userA newbranch-name
```